# CSS Center Responsive DIV

Tags: css, fluid-layout

The "tiles" (white boxes) that you see in image 1 are responsive to the users screen. If the screen size just isn't big enough, it leaves a gap on the right hand side. What I want to do is achieve the result as seen in image 2. Here is my code so far for those specific elements..

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.main{
    width:100%;
    background: #000;
}

.main .inner{
    margin:10px;
    min-width: 140px;
    background: red;
}

.main .inner .tile{
    margin:10px;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    background: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**IMAGE 1:** [image]

**IMAGE 2:** [image]

Comment: A single layout grid isn't able to support this at present. For an explanation of why not, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15231163/1306809). But multiple layout grids of different sizes can support it, using media queries to choose the right one based on the screen size, as @axrwkr suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with media queries to set the width of the `.inner` class at various browser widths, then set the `margin-left` and `margin-right` properties to `auto` to center it. Set the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` properties of the `.main` class instead of setting top and bottom margins on the `.inner` class. Use a combination of `padding` on the `.inner` class and `border` on the `.tile` class to space the tiles out evenly `10px` apart.

For a detailed description of media queries: [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/Media_queries)

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/axrwkr/eaefL)

css

```css
.main{
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.main .inner{
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 0px;
    display: table;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: red;
}

.main .inner .tile{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    background: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Set a media query for each browser width, in this example I have only gone up to 800px, but you can add as many more as you need.

css (continued)

```
@media (min-width: 280px) {
    .main .inner{
        width: 130px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 320px) {
    .main .inner{
        width: 260px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
    .main .inner{
        width: 390px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 640px) {
    .main .inner{
        width: 520px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
    .main .inner{
        width: 780px;
    }
}
```

The media queries are used to set the width of `.inner` to a multiple of `130px` which is the width of a `.tile` with a border of `10px`.

If you want to change the spacing between the tiles you would need to alter the `border` on the `.tile` class, the `padding` on the `.inner` class, the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` on the `.main` class and the `width` that is specified in each of the media queries.

Comment: This may be the only CSS solution available at present, using media queries to choose different layout grids based on the browser width. I think it's either that or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
   .main .inner{
  min-width: 140px;
    background: red;
    text-align:center;
    }
```

Add text-align:center css property  http://jsfiddle.net/dolours/afKgg/

Comment: Is there any way to made the last row aligned left?

Answer (score 0):

You could set max-width for `.inner` then have `text-align: center` for `.main`

Comment: Is there any way to made the last row aligned left?