# Any ideas on how I can centre the elements of the black outer div ? and make them responsive in size?

Tags: html, css

The following code consists of a label and a textbox and I need to centre them in the overall black container and when a window is changed in size they still stay right next to each other. Any ideas are very much appreciated, thank you

HTML:

```
 <div  style="position: relative; width: 100%; min-height: 68px; background-color: #000; border-top: 2px solid white; border-bottom: 2px solid white; overflow: hidden; padding-bottom: 2px" ng-switch on="isLoggedIn">
    <div style="position: relative; float: left; margin-left: 12px;">
            <div class="label" style="vertical-align: middle; color: #fff; margin-top: 8px;">Test</div>
        </div>

        <div style="position: relative; float: left;  margin-left: 12px;">
            <input type="number" class="theInput" min="1" />
            <label class="theLabel"><strong>&nbsp; $ </strong>  &nbsp;  |</label>
        </div>
        <div style="position: relative; float: left; margin-left: 12px;">
            <button type="submit"  ng-disabled="vm.isProcessing"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Center Responsive DIV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857276/css-center-responsive-div)

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the outer div:

```
<div style="position: relative; left:50%; translate: -50%;">
```

The relative position should move to the left the div and then the translate will adjust to the right to perfectly center it.